# Rendering HTML and converting it to PDF, content pagination and sizing

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, html-to-pdf

I render HTML codes and convert them to PDF with this C# and .NET 6 code and using the "Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore" library, but how can I do it when the content is too much? It became one page with the size of an A4 sheet (because I want to print the PDF), should I put the rest of the content on other pages?(By GoogleTranslate)

```
using SelectPdf;

try
            {
                HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

                converter.Options.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
                converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
                converter.Options.WebPageWidth = 1920;
                converter.Options.WebPageHeight = 1080;


                PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);
                doc.Save(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "PdfFolder", "PrintPDF.pdf"));
                doc.Close();
                return true;

            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
```

I didn't find a suitable answer, I only saw one way that could only paginate the text inside the `<p></p>` tag, but I want to paginate the body content and prepare it for printing.

Comment: Did you try to create a pdf with a content that does not fit into A4?